# how can we solve this python string problem

Tags: python, algorithm

if you have a string "MOBILE" and you have a number n=5 , then starting from M it would iterate 5 times which will remove L and displays it. , then starting from E it would iterate 4 times which will remove B and displays it. , then starting from I it would iterate 3 times which will remove M and displays it. , then starting from O it would iterate 2 times which will remove I and displays it.
, then starting from E it would iterate 1 time which will remove E and displays it. , finally displays remaining element O.

so we get the string LBMIEO

This is what i have come up with..i know its completely wrong...please someone guide me

```
string="mobile"
n=3

list1=[]
list2=[]
pos=-1

for items in string:
    list1.append(items)
    
while n>=0 :
    for i in range(0,n):
       pos=pos+1
       if pos==len(list1)+1:
            pos=0
            
    list2.append(list1[pos])
    list1.pop(pos)
    n=n-1
 

print(list2)
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly the logic is behind "starting from [..] iterate .. times"… Can you clarify?

Comment: Your question gives an example of what the code should do but does not explain the requirement that it is an example of.

Comment: I presume you're trying to remove `(letter index + n) % len(string)`?

Comment: look at `collections.deque`. rotate the deque in a loop decreasing number of positions (5, 4, 3,...) and pop/print the element at index 0

Comment: user inputs a word and a number(position) which is less than its length...the number should be in a loop and eventually get to 0..we have to loop through characters and delete it by position.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, (also suggested (first) by Buran):

```
from collections import deque

def f(s,n):
    d = deque(s)
    r = []
    while d:
        d.rotate(-n+1)
        r.append(d.popleft())
        n-=1
        
    return "".join(r)

assert f("MOBILE",5) == "LBMIEO"
```